# WebDav desktop sync tool similar to the OwnCloud / NextCloud desktop sync app?

Tags: software-recommendation, sync

I have been searching like crazy and can't find anything that works automatically and bi-directionally. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am able to reach my WebDav server using the the dolphin file browser on KDE, but that is a live connection to the WebDav server.

I am looking for something that works off-line if needed and when on-line it compares my local folder to the contents in the WebDav folder.

I am kind of surprised there isn't anything like this at the moment.

I guess I could use davfs to mount the WebDav folder but I would still need something automatic and in the background that did bi-directional syncs to go between the mounted WebDav folder and the local hard drive folder.

Any suggestions?

No, rsync won't work because it can't do bi-directional and you can't simply run it twice going in each direction or the deletes will cause trouble (or the copy will).